# How would you store the output of exec_command in paramiko with python

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko, python-2.6

```
import paramiko
import re
import getpass
username=raw_input("Enter the username: ")
password=getpass.getpass(prompt="Enter your password: ")
client = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.connect(host,22,username,password)
stdin, stdout, stderr= client.exec_command('cat /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf')
```

I'm looking to get the output of dhcpd.conf save it to a variable to parse and get the info that I need. I know that I cant print stdout and get the information that I am looking for but I do not see another way to send it to a variable.

This is in python 2.6.6 . Any help Is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

stdin, stdout, stderr are file handlers
You can read the output using `stdout.read() or stdout.readlines()`
You can assign that to variable